# What are the advantages of using a hetero-junction in Tunneling Field Effect Transistors (TFETs)?

Tags: condensed-matter, electronics, quantum-tunneling, nanoscience

What are the advantages of using a hetero-junction in [Tunneling Field Effect Transistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_field-effect_transistor) (TFETs)? How is the heterojunction able to improve the Ion/Ioff ratio of a TFET?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: In the link you give, there is no reference to a hetero-junction in the TFET. Can you elaborate on where in the device this hetero-junction is supposed to be inserted?